# Single File Archive+Copy+Extract Deployment for PC

Tags: windows-xp, batch, archiving

I've got some files on a machine that need to be archived, then copied over to another machine. On the other machine I need the files in a folder to be archived and removed, and then have the new archive extracted.

Basically overwrite a folder from a rar/zip and archive the old folder.

I have been able to create an exe from a batch file and include the 7zip utility, but the problem is that upon running the app the 7zip.exe gets extracted out of the batch executable, and is run as a separate program. The problem with this is that I can assign one exe to run securely, but not the extracted 7zip.exe.

Any ideas ?

Comment: the current solutions can extract a file, but cannot archive an old folder

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the archive as a self extracting file ?

Comment: because I cannot get that one to create an archive from the other folder

Answer (score 0):

Try IEXPRESS.EXE and see if that helps any. (it's included in Windows, most people don't realize it)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress